# module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tkinter'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Python3, I have a program written in Python2, I converted to Python3 using 2to3 command.

After running the code an error had occurred:

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tkinter'
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "pacman.py", line 679, in <module>    
    args = readCommand( sys.argv[1:] ) # Get game components based on input    
  File "pacman.py", line 567, in readCommand    
    import graphicsDisplay    
  File "graphicsDisplay.py", line 15, in <module>    
    from graphicsUtils import *    
  File "graphicsUtils.py", line 294, in <module>    
    def keys_pressed(d_o_e=tkinter.tkinter.dooneevent,    
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'tkinter'
```

Comment: I changed "tkinter.tkinter.dooneevent" to "kinter._tkinter.dooneevent" and it works! but another problem has occurred:
AttributeError: module '_tkinter' has no attribute 'dooneevent'